# My iOS app isn't requesting iAds

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, iad

I recently released my first app on the app store (August 5, 2014 release). When I was testing the app the test iAds seemed to never go away. Now, the actual app available on the app store isn't displaying any ads. I have read similar question, where iAds didn't work at first, but everyone says they started working after a little bit. However, mine seems unique in that it made six impressions right after it was first downloaded (6 requests, 6 impressions), but it hasn't done anything since. Is this a programming error and that's why my requests are low, or is this common for iAds on new apps?
Thanks. Oh, and I added ads using the method shown in this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u5XcVnHCQ0w The app uses Sprite Kit and was designed for iOS 7.0. There is only one view controller and it only displays banner ads. The app also uses Game Center if that is of any importance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

iAd takes a few days to look at new apps and then approves those for the iAd network. It is normal that you will have to wait a little bit.

Comment: The app says "Ad Status: Live Ads" It is still normal though, right? Thanks!

Comment: That is the normal notice for your ad. If it says live ads and you have impressions then you are getting ads successfully served to your app.